# Excel Function To Split Cell 3 Ways

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am wondering if there is a way to split a cell into three different cells.

I am working with City, State, Zip but they are all in the the same cell.

An example would be: Henly, TX 78620

All of the cells are formatted the same with the same spacing and all.

They originate in cell G, and need to be split so that the City stays in G, the State moves to H, and the zip moves to I.

Is this possible?

Comment: Text To Columns, split on the space and then remove the comma? Or, Text to Columns split on the comma, then Text to Columns split the output column on the space. That will handle city names which include a space character (e.g., "New York" or "Los Angeles"

Comment: You should learn how to ask a better question than this. Right now this is a lousy question which only asks "Is this possible" when probably what you mean is "How can I do this?"  Note also you're expected generally to demonstrate some effort towards solving the problem on your own. Have you tried *anything* yet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the cells in column **G** that contain the data you wish to parse and run this:

```
Sub Splitter()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In Selection
        ary = Split(r.Value, " ")
        r.Value = Left(ary(0), Len(ary(0)) - 1)
        r.Offset(0, 1).Value = ary(1)
        r.Offset(0, 2) = ary(2)
    Next r
End Sub
```

This will leave the City in **G** and move the other parts to the cells to the right.

**EDIT#1:**

Based on Scott's comments, here is another version:

```
Sub Splitter2()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In Selection
        ary = Split(r.Value, ",")
        r.Value = ary(0)
        bry = Split(Trim(ary(1)))
        r.Offset(0, 1).Value = bry(0)
        r.Offset(0, 2).Value = "'" & bry(1)
    Next r
End Sub
```

This version will:

1. handle multi-word city names
2. preserve any leading zeros in the ZIP code

Comment: @ScottCraner  You are correct!

Comment: @ScottCraner  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: @ScottCraner  Thanks for pointing out the flaws in the original code.